# Trying to record hidden and unhidden columns in columnmodel ExtJS 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

Trying to find out which columns are hidden and which are not.

Suppose I have table having columns

#### Name Place Animal Thing

Now I unhide the  Animal column.

#### Name Place Thing

my code is as below

```
var columnmodel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns:[
        {header: "Name", id: "id", , sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Name'},
        {header: "Place", id: "entityType", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'Place'},
        {header: "Animal", id: "title", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'title'},
        {header: "Thing", id: "title", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'title'},
    ],
    listeners: {
        {@link #hiddenchange}: function(cm, colIndex, hidden)   {
            saveConfig(colIndex, hidden);
        }
    }
});
```

Now when I'm running this getting the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Above error is in the line {@link #hiddenchange} so can someone help me why I'm facing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"{@link #hiddenchange}"` instead of `{@link #hiddenchange}`

Comment: Thanks @CD.. the error is gone.But can I print this on screen so that I can see the colmunmodel once a column is hidden ????

Comment: Thank You :) will figure out some way